# Read DataGrid content (C#,WPF)

Tags: c#-4.0, wpf-controls

How to read line per line the content of a DataGrid (System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid).

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to access the content of a DataGrid would be to iterate over the [DataGrid.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.itemssource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).